# SQL join column of 1 table to row of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have somewhat logical thing to do in SQL server, If my question is not valid or understandable pardon me , as I didn't knew how this question was supposed to be asked.

I have 2 tables which is to be converted into 3rd table.

1st table is a "Data" table having columns but their value is in codes whose TEXT which can be found in "Options" table.

```
State | Language | Gender
 2    |    3     |   1
```

2nd table is "Options" Table which is a master table for converting code of "Data" table into text.

Question column is columns of "Data" table.

Option column is Text corresponding to code.

Code column is Value of "Data column"'.

```
Question   |    Option      | Code
 State     |    Orissa      |   2
Language   |    English     |   3
```

Suppose I want the Text of State column for code : 2  in "Data" table then I would look into "Options" table and get the Option columns value 'Orissa' corrrsponding to State and code 2.

Resultant table should contain only Texts converted from codes.

```
 State     | Language       | Gender
 Orissa    |    English     |   1
```

1 thing to note is that Gender column didn't got converted text, because this column was 'NOT' contained in "Options table".

Result is to be created Dynamically as "Data" and "Options" table are created dynamically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly. What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Data" and "Options" table are created dynamically. are you saying the number of columns and column names  are mutable? or that state (for example) may sometimes appear as something different but with the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, Columns in "Data" table are dynamic , There are 3 "Data" tables and Their 3 corresponding "Options" table

Comment: In that case you need to enrich your question.

Comment: ok enrich it you can.

Answer (score 2):

Try joining your first table twice to the second table:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t2.Option, 'NA') AS State,
    COALESCE(t3.Option, 'NA') AS Language,
    t1.Gender
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.State = t2.Code AND t2.Question = 'State'
LEFT JOIN table2 t3
    ON t1.Language = t3.Code AND t3.Question = 'Language';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but can we create fully dynamic query,that will not be dependent on columns

Comment: I'm not so strong with dynamic SQL, but I also don't fully understand your comment.  What are you looking for here?

Comment: As we are selecting State and Language, which columns should be selected will not be known.

Comment: @ManojSoma your request makes no sense to me